# Docker: No such file or directory when trying to run docker inside docker

Tags: python, docker

Is docker binaries not available within docker? If so, how could I call it within docker?

app.py

```
import subprocess
cmd_payload = ['docker']
subprocess.Popen(cmd_payload, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
VOLUME /data
WORKDIR /data
ADD . /data
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Then, run

```
docker build -t app .
docker run app
```

OUTOUT:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

EDIT:
if i change

```
cmd_payload = ['docker']
```

to

```
cmd_payload = ['echo']
```

it doesnt throw an error. I would like to run docker executable . How could i do that?

Comment: Do you want to run docker within of a container?

Comment: @juliansalas yes

Comment: It may be better to use the [Python Docker library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docker).

Comment: Do you want to run [Docker in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) -- as in another instance of the Docker server inside a Docker container? Or do you just want to talk to the host's Docker server from a container?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run docker within of a container, the easy way to reach that is share docker daemon by volumes, Re-run your docker container with this:

`docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro app`

Moreover you have to add the  library  to Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libltdl7 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
VOLUME /data
WORKDIR /data
ADD . /data
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: my app within container cannot find docker executable. i dont think it's in my path? do i have to change it to /usr/bin/docker or something?

Comment: That's because your container does not have docker installed but not is necessary do that, just share the docker sock from your host to container.

Comment: How are you running your docker?

Answer (score 0):

subprocess was able to run docker executable by adding shell=True

```
cmd_payload = 'docker'
subprocess.Popen(cmd_payload, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Not sure why it couldnt find it if not invoked under a shell